# Good example of application that uses rails and backbone.js that handles authentication through backbone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, backbone.js

Does anybody know of a good example I could look at as to how to go about implementing authentication through backbone with rails?

I haven't been able to find anything..

Answer (score 2):

You have several possibilities. First you can log in normally, with plain html. That login would guide you to your backbone.js application.

Another possibility is within your backbone.js app you have a login form that takes advantage of backbone.js's ":authentication_token". When your backbone.js app sends the login info it will get a token back. From then on you are able make ajax calls and receive responses with that token.

EDIT: see this post for an example of working with the token: http://www.hyperionreactor.net/blog/token-based-authentication-rails-3-and-rails-2

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking about rails integration with client-side, except ajax queries and authentication/authorization?

Use the demo app to see how backbone.js is working: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/index.html

Comment: I just haven't been able to find any backbone examples that implement authentication and authorization. I'm using devise and just can't get my head around how to implement auth through backbone with it.

Comment: see the difference between a client and server side. First of all, start with plain html and make it work. Once have it work, you can build JS- driven application on top of it

Answer (score -1):

Found one example app. Trying to figure out what is what atm myself. But might be worth looking: https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora